# Archipack not showing in object mode

Tags: add-on

my first question here actually. I want to add a window using the archipack addon. I already enabled the addon, chose a location for the material library, and rendered presets thumbs. For some reason, when I press shift+A the archipack isn't showing up. When I press shift+A in edit mode, I can select archipack, but of course I can't add a new object in edit mode so it doesn't work. Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to solve it myself. I pressed "n" to open the sidebar, then I went to the create tab and there it was.